# What's meant by the "two" in the idiom "take two and then we'll talk"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms

I'm curious about what "take two" means, I guess more about what the unit of measure meant by the idiom "take two" is.

Comment: It is a paraphrase of the idiom, "it takes two" to.... https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/it-takes-two - Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280221/the-origin-of-it-takes-two-to-tango

Comment: @Josh - I doubt it.  it either means take two minutes ( to cool down) and then we can talk when you can be reasonable.  OR it means take two pills (Valium etc) so you can calm down and then  we’ll talk.

Comment: The guy's obviously in a hurry. Most people *take **five** [**minutes** away from the current task, by way of rest/refreshment]*.

Comment: First off, I don't think this is an *idiom*, because a google search for that exact phrase yields no results, nor does a search of newspaper archives or google books.  @Jim is right, in context it probably means minutes or pills.  Taking "two" of a pill or product is a common marketing strategy that's often associated with the Alka-Seltzer jingle, "Plop Plop, Fizz Fizz."

Comment: This is possibly a mash up of "take five" as an idiom for take a five minute break and a doctor saying "take two aspirin and call me in the morning".

Comment: Down-voting because you failed to provide any context.

Comment: Take two aspirin and call me in the morning .. is one idiom

Answer (score 1):

"Take two/five/ten" is an idiom, likely derived from musicians jargon, that means "take a break" or "rest a bit".  The full sentence would be something like "Let's take a two/five/ten minute break" (where "break" means "rest period"), but obviously such wording tends to be shortened.  (And it should be noted that the specified time interval often should not be interpreted literally.)

However, the most idiomatic forms are "take five" and "take ten", so one might suspect (absent the context which Opie carelessly omitted) that the meaning of "take two" is "second take of a scene while filming a movie", or it's short for "take two aspirin (or other drug) and call me in the morning", or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yea @[Jim](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/17956/jim) is right. It is either minutes or doses recommended by the doctor. Also, it probably is a saying/phrase rather than an idiom.